# Как сохранить настройки интерфейса в PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, интерфейс, plsql

Использую *PL/SQL Developer* 10-й версии.

Как сохранить настройки интерфейса и расположение окон?

Вообще, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать команду меню Window -> Save Layout.

[image: Настройка сохранения расположения окон]

Comment: То, что надо. Спасибо =)